# FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)) when flutter app is re-installed

Tags: flutter, io

I am having a weird behavior when I am trying to read a an external file that already created with a flutter app when I re-install the app. Reading and writing work just fine but when I uninstall the app and run it again it gives me FileSystemException.
I created a very simple all to demonstration the issue.
I am really stuck and ran out of solutions!

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _message = '';
  String _content = '';

  void _writeFile() {
    setState(() {
      File file = File('/storage/emulated/0/Documents/test2.txt');
      if (file.existsSync()) {
        _message = 'File already exsists';
        _content = '';
      } else {
        String fileContent = '{"key","value"}';
        file.writeAsString(fileContent);
        _message = 'File created';
        _content = fileContent;
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> _readFile() async {
    {
      File file = File('/storage/emulated/0/Documents/test2.txt');
      if (!file.existsSync()) {
        _message = 'File is not there!';
      } else {
        _message = 'File read :';
        _content = await file.readAsString();
      }
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_message),
            const Text(''),
            Text(_content),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(width: 100),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _writeFile,
            tooltip: 'Write',
            child: const Text('Write'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 100),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _readFile,
            tooltip: 'Read',
            child: const Text('Read'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulhyL.png)

Comment: have you added storage permission in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I tried that but no luck as well. Note that I can write and read at first. But only when I uninstall the app and try to run it again it gives me that error.

Comment: You should ask a user to provide permission to use storage, to do that you can use permission_handler package: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: @MaksimNikolaev This is not a valid solution as it gives access to manage ALL external storage. This is a behavior that the users might not accept. In addition, Google will not accept the app in the play store.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this issue is related to permissions system of Android/iOS.
Check this package, I think it's gonna solve your problem.

[permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

You need to add something like this:

```
var status = await Permission.storage.status;
if (status.isDenied) {
  Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
    Permission.location,
    Permission.storage,
  ].request();
} else {
  // Your method calls here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked permission handler but I could not find a permission other than 
MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  which will allow the app to access all the files in the device. This is something that we do not want and I believe google will not accept that when you publish in the play store.